# How does vertical-align of one inline block affect its neighboring inline blocks?

Tags: html, css

I am trying to understand the vertical align  property in css. 
When I set vertical-align = bottom for only the span only it moves down. Same happens for div also . However when I set the vertical-align = bottom for only the p , both the div and span move. This behavior is captured in the image attached below .

My HTML:

```
<html>

<head>
  <title>
  </title>
</head>

<body>
  <span>span1</span>
  <div>div1</div>
  <p>paragraph A</p>
</body>

</html>
```

MY CSS:

```
span {
  height: 50px;
  width: 75px;
  background: #00FF00;
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: ;
}

div {
  height: 100px;
  width: 50px;
  background: #00FFFF;
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: ;
}

p {
  height: 200px;
  width: 200px;
  background: #FF00FF;
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: bottom;
}
```

[image: see case 2 : even though set for p both div and span change the position]

In above image , only vertical-align  property is changed in code above and only of the specified factor .  See case 2 : even though set for p both div and span change the position

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've created a modified example of yours so we can see exactly why this happens.
I've added a `wrapper` div to see exactly the edges of the lines we're aligning items to.

I've also left all items with no `vertical-align` assigned, and if you click on one, it removes the property from its siblings and adds `vertical-align: bottom` to the one you've clicked.

We can see that the reason is that your original `p` which now is my `p.big` takes up the *full height* of the container line, so there's nothing really to align. When you apply `vertical-align` to it, then it affects **all of its siblings on the line** to take on that value as well.

Otherwise, it behaves accordingly as the documentation, it aligns itself relative to the line, and doesn't affect any other element but itself.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
 $('span, .el, p').click(function(e){
   $('span, .el, p').removeClass("v-bottom");
    $(this).addClass("v-bottom");
  })
})
```

```css
.wrapper{
  border-top:1px dashed;
  border-bottom:1px dashed;
}
span,
div.el,
p{
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  line-height: 1;
}

span {
  height: 50px;
  width: 75px;
  background: green;
  display: inline-block;
}

div.el {
  height: 100px;
  width: 50px;
  background: yellow;
  display: inline-block;
}

p.big {
  height: 200px;
  width: 200px;
  background: blue;
  display: inline-block;
}
p.small {
  height: 50px;
  width: 100px;
  background: red;
  display: inline-block;
}

.v-bottom{
  vertical-align: bottom;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="wrapper">

<span>span1</span>
<div class="el">div1</div>
<p class="big">paragraph A</p>
<p class="small">paragraph A</p>
</div>
```

Comment: When I click on blue coloured paragraph ,the yellow div moves down to the bottom . But why green coloured span and red paragraph have not moved to the bottom too ?